# DTrace: Tracing user stack size on OS X? (curthread->t_procp->p_stksize?)

Tags: macos, stack-trace, callstack, dtrace

I've come across this simple DTrace script for tracing user stack sizes, but it doesn't work on OS X Mountain Lion:

```
dtrace -n 'sched:::on-cpu { @[execname] = max(curthread->t_procp->p_stksize);}'
```

(from: http://www.solarisinternals.com/wiki/index.php/DTrace_Topics_One_Liners)

The error returned on OS X is:

```
dtrace: invalid probe specifier sched:::on-cpu { @[execname] =
  max(curthread->t_procp->p_stksize);}: in action list:
  t_procp is not a member of struct thread
```

Indeed, I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what the valid members of "curthread" are on OS X. Is there an equivalent way to drill down to the current user stack size for the thread? Or is "curthread" just an opaque pointer on OS X, usable only for thread identification? Note that I'd be just as happy to do this tracing via the "pid" provider, if that helps any.

Thanks!

Comment: The `struct thread` for OSX is available here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2050.9.2/osfmk/kern/thread.h

Comment: Thanks, that's certainly interesting, but I still don't know how to get from there to a user stack size, since the OS X struct is different from the (presumed) Solaris struct above which features t_procp->p_stksize.

Comment: From searching various sources, there doesn't seem to be a OSX equivalent.  Try `apropos dtrace` from the command line to see the scripts provided with the Mac; none of them appear to provide what you are looking for, so you might have to write this yourself.

Comment: On Solaris, curthread->t_procp->p_stksize is the size, in bytes, of the memory segment set aside for the process's stack.  Is this really what you wanted (cf. [Devin Beyer's reply](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32072819/1579636))?